# How can I implement Webhooks with ASP.NET (or some other technology) to execute a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I would like to be able to execute a powershell script on a Win10 box called `MyServices` which when called with either HTTP POST or HTTP GET `http://MyServices/foobar/<hex hash code>` will execute a powershell script that resides on `MyServices`.

Or, alternatively and preferably is there a utility that can work over my local network that I can send a command from another machine that can execute the script for me?  I don’t want to reinvent the wheel of something like this already exists.

ETA:  I’m running a Linux machine that’s going to initiate the powershell script.  And to make it more complicated, this is a service running under docker.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Take a look at [PS Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions) to execute PowerShell commands on remote computers.

Comment: can you use ps remoting from a Linux machine?

Comment: You can use PS Remoting from [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-6#basic-authentication-limitations-on-linux-and-macos) to connect to Windows Machines.